# Powershell Encypt and Python Decrypt

Tags: python, powershell, encryption, aes

I have a database that is being retired, but stores "secrets" and I need to be able to encrypt the data and save to a windows machine and then decrypt on a linux machine.

I've got the encryption piece in powershell working, however, I don't know that I'm feeding the encyption key and initialization vector correctly into python because it's not being decrypted correctly.

here is the powershell code to read the plaintext passwords and encrypt them:

```
$key = New-Object Byte[] 32
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($key)

$AES = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged
$iv = $AES.IV
$key = $AES.Key

$iv | Out-File IV.key
$key | Out-File AES.key 

$raw = Get-Content -Path .\passwords.txt -Raw

foreach ($line in -split $raw) {
    $secure_pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $line -AsPlainText -Force
    $encrypted_pass = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $secure_pass -key $key 
    $encrypted_pass | Add-Content encrypted_passes.txt
}
```

and this is the decryption code in python:

```
rom Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


key = open("AES.key","r")
iv = open("IV2.key","r")
password_file = open("encrypted_passes.txt","r")
iv_text = iv.read()
key_text = key.read()
iv_base = base64.b64encode(iv_text)
print "IV: " + iv_base[:16]
base_key = base64.b64encode(key_text)
aes = AES.new(base_key[:32], AES.MODE_CBC, iv_base[:16])
print len(iv_base)

for line in password_file:
        print line
        print "blah: " + aes.decrypt(line[:32])
```

I would like python to read the encrypted password file and be able to decrypt it correctly.